# Moving Headers/Libraries/Executables to specific directories

Tags: cmake

I've recently started using CMake for one of my multi-platform projects, but I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to do something.

Basically, inside the project I've got multiple libraries and executables, all in their own folders. I would like to place all of the compiled libraries into one directory on build i.e. a lib folder inside the CMake build folder. I would like to do the same things for the executables.

```
CMake Build Directory

| ----------> bin (where i want the executables to go)

| ----------> lib (where i want the libraries to go)

| ----------> utils (where the libraries are ordinarily compiled)

| ----------> test (where the executables are ordinarily compiled)
```

There are directories inside utils and apps for all the different libraries and executables I'm making. I have a CMakeLists in the base folder of my source directory which adds all the subdirectories. If anything does not make sense then feel free to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use this:

```
  set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin )
  set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib )
  set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib )
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at [install](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3ainstall) CMake command.

Here example from that page:

```
install(TARGETS myExe mySharedLib myStaticLib
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/static)
install(TARGETS mySharedLib DESTINATION /some/full/path)
```

So you can use CMAKE_BINARY_DIR instead /some/full/path

Comment: Note: the effect will only actually be achieved with `make install`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, for includes:

`install( FILES ${HEADERS}
          DESTINATION inc )`

*[when set of header files to be installed]*

`install( DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
          DESTINATION inc)`

*[when header directory to be installed]*

[More Info](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html)