# How to copy the binary output of one target into the binary folder of another target?

Tags: cmake

I'm building a dynamic library that is meant to be loaded dynamically like a plugin.  When present, the library is loaded.  When not present, it can't.

Naturally, I made a test app...and it doesn't work.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(MYLIB)

enable_testing()
INCLUDE(CPack)

SET(SRCS
    src/source1.cpp
    src/source2.cpp
)

ADD_LIBRARY(mylib SHARED ${SRCS})

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(test)
```

**test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test_loader main.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test_loader dl)

ADD_TEST(NAME test_loader COMMAND test_loader)
```

**test/main.c**

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void* handle;

    handle = dlopen("./mylib.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    if (handle == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    }

    return 1;
}
```

**and then to build**

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

The result is that there is a `mylib.so` file in `/build`.  There is a `test_loader` executable in `/build/test`.

And this doesn't work out.

**What I need is for there to be a copy of `mylib.so` under `/build/test/` so that I can dynamically load it with the test app.**

Comment: If you want *mylib.so* to be **created** under *build/test*, set *CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_VARIABLE* accordingly, as describe in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293769/moving-headers-libraries-executables-to-specific-directories/6303608#6303608). If you want *mylib.so* to be **existed both** under *build/* and under *build/test/*, just create appropriate target for copy library file, as it is described in [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474659/cmake-how-to-have-a-target-for-copying-files?rq=1).

Comment: If I used the CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY method, is there any reason to have both copies exist?

Comment: `is there any reason to have both copies exist?` - Normally, there is not. But it is fully depends on your needs. E.g., you may have *another* user of your library, which want to have it in another special directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the answers given helped me greatly (and anyone reading this should review those answers as well as the comments), I found an even better solution:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET test_loader POST_BUILD 
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "$<TARGET_FILE:mylib>" $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:test_loader>)
```

This solution results in two copies of the library.  One copy is next to the test_loader, so that the unit tests can work.  The other is in the default output location.  Since it's still in the default output location, other projects that depend on `mylib` know where to find them, by default.

Answer (score 0):

There are cmake variables that let you control where libraries, shared libraries, and executables are placed. See cmake documentation [Variables that Control the Build](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#id5). I do not think it is a good idea to mix executables and libraries. (Of course this is my opinion--you can use whatever layout you want.) I use the following:

```
# Directory for output files
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib 
    CACHE PATH "Output directory for static libraries.")

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
    CACHE PATH "Output directory for shared libraries.")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
    CACHE PATH "Output directory for executables and DLL's.")
```

If you used this, then you would need to adjust your dlopen statement to `handle = dlopen("../lib/libmylib.so", RTLD_LAZY);` Note that I adjusted the name of mylib because I believe cmake will, by default on Linux, use a `lib` prefix when naming libraries.